# Rollback magento 2.2.4 givers delimitor error

Tags: magento2, php, sql

I hope someone can help me with this; i was testing some modules and didnt like them so decided to do a rollback, offcourse a backup was made so i had no worries in the sky......

But my nightmare became true when the rollback gave error

The system was quite barfed up so i used ssh.

first ;

> php -d memory_limit=1536M bin/magento setup:rollback -d backup.sql

gave a ;

> Segmentation fault

so i did ;

> ulimit -s 65536

and again

> php -d memory_limit=1536M bin/magento setup:rollback -d backup.sql

which gave

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter' at line 1, query was: delimiter ;;

I increased the memory to the max of 4096, no effect
I tried it on user and root , no effect

then I said to myself ; WHO NEEDS THIS, just use mysql itself
so ;

via **ssh cli**

> mysql -umysecretusername -p mydatabasename < backup.sql

gave an error ;

> ERROR at line 302: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected.

so I did ;

Which gave an error ;

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 303: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '7559','6','Magento_Cms::config_cms',NULL,'deny'),('7560','6','Magento_Newsletter' at line 1

so I am quite lost at the moment, I filtered my sql file and show the delimiter actions in down below

any help or people who had the same problem?

### ===this is below===

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_category_entity`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_category_entity_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_entity_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_category_entity FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_category_entity_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_entity_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_category_entity FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`attribute_set_id` != OLD.`attribute_set_id` OR NEW.`parent_id` != OLD.`parent_id` OR NEW.`created_at` != OLD.`created_at` OR NEW.`path` != OLD.`path` OR NEW.`position` != OLD.`position` OR NEW.`level` != OLD.`level` OR NEW.`children_count` != OLD.`children_count`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_category_entity_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_entity_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_category_entity FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_category_entity_int`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_category_entity_int FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_category_entity_int FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_entity_int_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_category_entity_int FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_category_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_category_product`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_category_product_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_product_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_category_product FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_category_product_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_product_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_category_product FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`category_id` != OLD.`category_id` OR NEW.`product_id` != OLD.`product_id` OR NEW.`position` != OLD.`position`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`); END IF;
>   IF (NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`category_id` != OLD.`category_id` OR NEW.`product_id` != OLD.`product_id` OR NEW.`position` != OLD.`position`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_category_product_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_category_product_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_category_product FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_product_entity`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`attribute_set_id` != OLD.`attribute_set_id` OR NEW.`type_id` != OLD.`type_id` OR NEW.`sku` != OLD.`sku` OR NEW.`has_options` != OLD.`has_options` OR NEW.`required_options` != OLD.`required_options` OR NEW.`created_at` != OLD.`created_at`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   IF (NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`attribute_set_id` != OLD.`attribute_set_id` OR NEW.`type_id` != OLD.`type_id` OR NEW.`sku` != OLD.`sku` OR NEW.`has_options` != OLD.`has_options` OR NEW.`required_options` != OLD.`required_options` OR NEW.`created_at` != OLD.`created_at`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_product_entity FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_product_entity_datetime`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity_datetime FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity_datetime FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_product_entity_datetime FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_product_entity_decimal`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity_decimal FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity_decimal FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_decimal_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_product_entity_decimal FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_product_entity_gallery`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity_gallery FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity_gallery FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`position` != OLD.`position` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_gallery_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_product_entity_gallery FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_product_entity_int`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity_int FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity_int FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_product_entity_int FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_product_entity_text`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity_text FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity_text FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_text_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_product_entity_text FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_tier_price_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_tier_price_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity_tier_price FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_tier_price_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_tier_price_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity_tier_price FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`all_groups` != OLD.`all_groups` OR NEW.`customer_group_id` != OLD.`customer_group_id` OR NEW.`qty` != OLD.`qty` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value` OR NEW.`percentage_value` != OLD.`percentage_value` OR NEW.`website_id` != OLD.`website_id`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`all_groups` != OLD.`all_groups` OR NEW.`customer_group_id` != OLD.`customer_group_id` OR NEW.`qty` != OLD.`qty` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value` OR NEW.`percentage_value` != OLD.`percentage_value` OR NEW.`website_id` != OLD.`website_id`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_tier_price_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_tier_price_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_product_entity_tier_price FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity_varchar FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity_varchar FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   IF (NEW.`value_id` != OLD.`value_id` OR NEW.`attribute_id` != OLD.`attribute_id` OR NEW.`store_id` != OLD.`store_id` OR NEW.`entity_id` != OLD.`entity_id` OR NEW.`value` != OLD.`value`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_varchar_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_product_entity_varchar FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`entity_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalog_product_website`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_website_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_website_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_website FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_website_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_website_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_website FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`product_id` != OLD.`product_id` OR NEW.`website_id` != OLD.`website_id`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalog_product_website_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_website_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalog_product_website FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `cataloginventory_stock_item`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON cataloginventory_stock_item FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `cataloginventory_stock_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON cataloginventory_stock_item FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`item_id` != OLD.`item_id` OR NEW.`product_id` != OLD.`product_id` OR NEW.`stock_id` != OLD.`stock_id` OR NEW.`qty` != OLD.`qty` OR NEW.`min_qty` != OLD.`min_qty` OR NEW.`use_config_min_qty` != OLD.`use_config_min_qty` OR NEW.`is_qty_decimal` != OLD.`is_qty_decimal` OR NEW.`backorders` != OLD.`backorders` OR NEW.`use_config_backorders` != OLD.`use_config_backorders` OR NEW.`min_sale_qty` != OLD.`min_sale_qty` OR NEW.`use_config_min_sale_qty` != OLD.`use_config_min_sale_qty` OR NEW.`max_sale_qty` != OLD.`max_sale_qty` OR NEW.`use_config_max_sale_qty` != OLD.`use_config_max_sale_qty` OR NEW.`is_in_stock` != OLD.`is_in_stock` OR NEW.`low_stock_date` != OLD.`low_stock_date` OR NEW.`notify_stock_qty` != OLD.`notify_stock_qty` OR NEW.`use_config_notify_stock_qty` != OLD.`use_config_notify_stock_qty` OR NEW.`manage_stock` != OLD.`manage_stock` OR NEW.`use_config_manage_stock` != OLD.`use_config_manage_stock` OR NEW.`stock_status_changed_auto` != OLD.`stock_status_changed_auto` OR NEW.`use_config_qty_increments` != OLD.`use_config_qty_increments` OR NEW.`qty_increments` != OLD.`qty_increments` OR NEW.`use_config_enable_qty_inc` != OLD.`use_config_enable_qty_inc` OR NEW.`enable_qty_increments` != OLD.`enable_qty_increments` OR NEW.`is_decimal_divided` != OLD.`is_decimal_divided` OR NEW.`website_id` != OLD.`website_id`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `cataloginventory_stock_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_cataloginventory_stock_item_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON cataloginventory_stock_item FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `cataloginventory_stock_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`product_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;

--

### -- Triggers structure for table `catalogrule`

> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalogrule_after_insert;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalogrule_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalogrule FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_rule_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`rule_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalogrule_after_update;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalogrule_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalogrule FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   IF (NEW.`rule_id` != OLD.`rule_id` OR NEW.`name` != OLD.`name` OR NEW.`description` != OLD.`description` OR NEW.`from_date` != OLD.`from_date` OR NEW.`to_date` != OLD.`to_date` OR NEW.`is_active` != OLD.`is_active` OR NEW.`conditions_serialized` != OLD.`conditions_serialized` OR NEW.`actions_serialized` != OLD.`actions_serialized` OR NEW.`stop_rules_processing` != OLD.`stop_rules_processing` OR NEW.`sort_order` != OLD.`sort_order` OR NEW.`simple_action` != OLD.`simple_action` OR NEW.`discount_amount` != OLD.`discount_amount`) THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_rule_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`rule_id`); END IF;
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_catalogrule_after_delete;
>   delimiter ;;
>   CREATE  TRIGGER trg_catalogrule_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON catalogrule FOR EACH ROW
>   BEGIN
>   INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_rule_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (OLD.`rule_id`);
>   END
>   ;;
>   delimiter ;
>
> /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
>   /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */; 
>   /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
>   /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
>   /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
>   /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
>   /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
>
> -- Dump completed on 2018-07-18 14:47:34 GMT

Comment: I am trying to find out what happened, so installed mysqlworkbench, connected it with the server and tried to put the triggers in with a query, that seems to work, so i decided to enter the whole sql, first as a file, but the workbench gave errors, so i tried to copie the sql into workbench  (16Mb), and it gave me some clarification about the errors.

Comment: I have somehow a disturbance in the force let me show;   4,'simple','7999',0,0,'2018-06-07 20:59:13','2018-07-08 19:26:46'),('412',4,'simple','900005',0,0,'2018-06-07 20:59:13','hhÄèePçehh h@ hhh h@ h,4,'simple','7998',0,0,'2018-06-07 20:59:13','2018-07-08 19:27:00'),('415',4,'simple','7858',etc etc you can see the "hhÄèePçehh h@ h" there, it flies around in the sql, and all the errors i find are in a line with this tekst line..... any ideas what it is?

Comment: And workbench gives it also as an error, if i put a ') behind it, the line goes green and workbench happy....